# Can someone help me with my Hangman guessing letter issue?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently working on a project for my coding class, and I'm having issues with my code. My code is adding correct letters to the wrongLetters array and I'm unsure why. It also only does this for the second correct letter and onward being inputted, meaning that if I guessed one correct letter correctly it would add it to the correctLetters array, however every correct letter after that would result in it being added both to correctLetters and wrongLetters when it should only be added to correctLetters. If you can help please do, I'm very confused. Thank you.

[This link will bring to my current code on CodePen. With the HTML and CSS. You will find the issue in the JS portion of my code thank you, which is below as well.](https://codepen.io/MilkyBOii/pen/LyPdRp?editors=0011)

```
var guessWords = ["school", "test", "quiz", "pencil", "ruler", "protractor", "teacher", "homework", "science", "math", "english", "history", "language", "elective", "bully", "grades", "recess", ]
var secretWord = guessWords[Math.floor(Math.random()*guessWords.length)];
var wrongLetters = []
var correctLetters = []
var repeatLetters = []
function startGame() {
  var testWord = document.getElementById("randTest").innerHTML = secretWord; 
  var correctLettersOUT = "";
    document.getElementById("currentGuess").innerHTML = secretBlanks(secretWord)
    function secretBlanks(secretWord) {
      for (var i = 0; i < secretWord.length; i++) {
        correctLettersOUT+=("_ ");
        } return correctLettersOUT;

}}
function correctWord() {
  var guessLetter = document.getElementById("guessLetter").value;
  document.getElementById("letter").innerHTML = guessLetter;

 for (i=0; i < secretWord.length; i++) {
     if (correctLetters.indexOf(guessLetter) === -1)

        if (guessLetter === secretWord[i]) {
          correctLetters.push(guessLetter);
        } else if(wrongLetters.indexOf(guessLetter) === -1) {
          wrongLetters.push(guessLetter);
        }
 }

  console.log(correctLetters);
  console.log(wrongLetters);
  console.log(repeatLetters);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See conditions in your for loop - in first iteration, if letter is different from first letter of secret word and is not present in `wrongLetters` then you add it to this array. 
First check whether secret word contains letter and then decide which array should contain this letter. (BTW. why checking it in loop when you can use `indexOf` or in ES6 `includes` function?)

Answer (score 0):

```
var guessWords = ["school", "test", "quiz", "pencil", "ruler", "protractor", "teacher", "homework", "science", "math", "english", "history", "language", "elective", "bully", "grades", "recess", ]
var secretWord = guessWords[Math.floor(Math.random()*guessWords.length)];
var wrongLetters = []
var correctLetters = []
var repeatLetters = []
function startGame() {
  var testWord = document.getElementById("randTest").innerHTML = secretWord; 
  var correctLettersOUT = "";
    document.getElementById("currentGuess").innerHTML = secretBlanks(secretWord)
    function secretBlanks(secretWord) {
      for (var i = 0; i < secretWord.length; i++) {
        correctLettersOUT+=("_ ");
        } return correctLettersOUT;

}}
function correctWord() {
  var guessLetter = document.getElementById("guessLetter").value;
  document.getElementById("letter").innerHTML = guessLetter;

 for (var i = 0; i < secretWord.length; i++) {
     if (correctLetters.indexOf(guessLetter) === -1)

        if (guessLetter === secretWord[i]) {
          correctLetters.push(guessLetter);
          break;
        }
 }
    if(wrongLetters.indexOf(guessLetter) === -1 && correctLetters.indexOf(guessLetter) === -1) {
         wrongLetters.push(guessLetter);
    }

  console.log(correctLetters);
  console.log(wrongLetters);
  console.log(repeatLetters);
}
```

The problem was that the code that added letters to the `wrongLetters` array was inside the for loop that was checking for correct letters, so if the correct letter was lets say letter 2 the loop would check against letter 1 and then add it to the `wrongLetters` array because it was not the same letter.

I moved the check to outside of the loop and now letters are added to the correct array. Right now if you guess the same letter more then once it will be added to the correctLetters array multiple times,

if you don't want that behavior just change the first if check from

`if (guessLetter === secretWord[i])`

to

`if (guessLetter === secretWord[i] && correctLetters.indexOf(guessLetter) === -1)`

Comment: Thank you so much!